# FastReport aspcore 404 error in production /_fr path unavailable

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, fastreport

We are running into an error when trying to deploy our asp.net core application to production with FastReport. It seems that when the report preview is generated, it creates a bunch of resource and file system links to the path /_fr

When we deploy the application on IIS in production, the application lives in a folder structure of its own: http://www.ourdomain.com/OurApp  (C:\inetpub\OurApp)

The application pool for the application doesn't have access to the root folder under inetpub. When generating a report for preview, FastReport tries to write all of these resources to C:\inetpub\_fr...
and the URLs used to access these resources are

http://www.ourdomain.com/_fr/resources.getResource?resourceName=magnifier.svg&contentType=image%2Fsvg%2Bxml
http://www.ourdomain.com/_fr/resources.getResource?resourceName=spinner.svg&contentType=image%2Fsvg%2Bxml
http://www.ourdomain.com/_fr/resources.getResource?resourceName=reload.svg&contentType=image%2Fsvg%2Bxml
http://www.ourdomain.com/_fr/preview.getReport?reportId=b43add31c4b64cc0a111ded240c9b565&renderBody=yes

We've tried changing the ROOT_BASE_PATH but it doesn't seem to help.

There's no problem if we export straight to PDF. It is only an issue with the preview function.

```
@if (ViewBag.WebReport != null)
    {
        @await ViewBag.WebReport.Render();
    }
```

Any insight to this issue would be helpful. We can't find documentation that explains how the preview is actually supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an error caused by permissions, First of all, shouldn't the App be under wwwroot? You can try to move your "OurApp" to the wwwroot folder and try again. Then check if the IIS_IUSRS has permission for the wwwroot folder. By default, the IIS user does not have write permissions for the wwwroot folder.

1.Open File Explorer and go to C:/inetpub/

2.Right click on wwwroot and click on "Properties"

3.Go to the Security tab and click "Edit..." to edit permissions

4.Find and select the IIS user. In my case, it was called IIS_IUSRS ([server name]\IIS_IUSRS).

5.Select the "Allow" checkbox for all permissions.

Comment: Because this is a production environment, I don't have any control over where the app is ultimately deployed. As with any net.core asp app there is a wwwroot folder in the app configuration. It maps to /OurApp in the production IIS server. The problem is that FastReport is using an absolute path to the root (/) of the app server rather than the root of the Web App.

Comment: Have you tried to add all permissions to inetpub for IIS_IUSRS?

Comment: samwu - again this is a production environment. We do not have the ability to alter security for the filesystem.

Comment: You say the application pool for the application doesn't have access to the root folder under inetpub, since you don’t have permission for this, the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: We are currently in the process of reviewing the open source with a view towards an update of the preview process to use a specified directory and root url which can be set independently during the FastReport initialization at app startup. By determining the "site root" at startup and its corresponding physical path we believe we can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know it was 4 months ago but I just figuring out myself so I just post it here.

**1. Add FastReport.OpenSource.Web as nuget dependency**

- Double-click on your project then add this line.

```html
<PackageReference Include="FastReport.OpenSource.Web" Version="*" />
```

**2. Register at Startup class**

- Go to Startup.cs
- Find Configure's public and add **app.UseFastReport()**;

```c#
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseFastReport();
    ...
}
```

3. Rebuild your project and check if it work

P/S: It actually on [their github website](https://fastreports.github.io/FastReport.Documentation/WebReport.html) but not everyone knew so I just leave it here

Comment: The question was not about how to register FastReport. It was to do with relocating the temporary files generated in the preview so that we could move the whole application to a multi-tenant host which puts our application in a tree past the root of the website.